# Polymer - Select DOM Element from if template

Tags: polymer

I'm learning Polymer. I have a view that is setup like this:

**my-view.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-view">   
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[ areAvailable ]]">
      <my-component id="myComponent"></my-component>
      <button type="button" on-click="onButtonClick">Test</button>
    </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="[[ !areAvailable ]]">
      <div>Move along</div>
    <template>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:'my-view',
      properties: {
        areAvailable: Boolean
      },

      onButtonClick: function() {
        this.$.myComponent.test();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This view shows `my-component` based on the `areAvailable` flag. If a user clicks the "Test" button, I need to execute a function in `my-component`. `my-component` is setup like this:

**my-component.html**

```
<dom-module id="my-component">  
  <template>
    <h1>hello there!</h1>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:'my-component',    
      test: function() {
        alert('voila!');
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

My challenge is, my approach works **IF** `my-component` is *not* inside of an "if" template. When `my-component` is inside of an "if" template, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note**: Nodes created dynamically using data binding (including those in `dom-repeat` and `dom-if` templates) are not added to the `this.$` hash. The hash includes only **statically created local DOM nodes** (that is, the nodes defined in the element’s outermost template).

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding

Since you have already added a listener to the click event on your button, you can redefine that listener like this:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  onButtonClick: function() {
    // The this.root here refers to the local dom
    // It is highly advised that you use Polymer.dom(<node>) when doing dom manipulations
    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#myComponent').test(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Polymer have this simple function...

```
this.$$('#myComponent')
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding